# Corrupted PHP/HTML files

Tags: php, html, corruption

I'm building some pages for a website. I've used Teleport Pro to fetch the HTML files and placed them in my Wamp server's www folder. I've added a few PHP/HTML files of my own to the project and backed up the entire wamp folder when my SSD was dying - using copy-paste.

The problem is that somehow the PHP/HTML text files that I've built and now need desperatly have been corrupted: they're full of '\00' characters.

Here is such a file: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2532807/conference.html

[image]

Is there anything I can try to recover the content of such files?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand (your link leads to an empty page), but if you replace all '\00' occurences with '' (with an editor such as Notepadd ++ for example), wouldn't it be ok ?

Comment: I added the link so you can download the file and view it with an editor. I've posted a screenshot from NP++. I can't replace anything, because the files have no useful chars - just '\00' or NUL.

Comment: That happens when the pasting process is interrupted, generally... I don't think you can recover from actual files the old content !

Comment: @Alarid bummer; I have abandoned the old files and started fresh.